# trying to get mvn jboss-as:start for Jboss but not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

Moving to JBoss AS 7 from Tomcat.. I need help with maven run..  I download and have running JBoss AS7 and from the command line I can do a

**mvn jboss-as:deploy** to deploy my project on a running JBoss AS 7 but I am trying to get working

**mvn jboss-as:start** that would start a JBoss AS7 but this does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This

> mvn jboss-as:start

is not one of the [JBoss AS 7 maven plugin goals](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/plugin-info.html). I think the one you want is:

> mvn jboss-as:run

Comment: if I do this I get unsatisfied dependencies... I think its due to it looking for a JNDI data source

Comment: Which dependencies is it complaining about specifically?